# Android Studio Theme Editor not doing anything

Tags: android

I don't know what's happened to Android Studio in the last 12 weeks but it's turned into a pathetic, buggy IDE and I'm absolutely fed up with it.

All I want to do is change the theme of my application, and every time I open the Theme Editor and change the theme, it does absolutely nothing. Doesn't change the theme, doesn't change any colours. I open the Theme Editor back up and see that it has reverted back to the previous theme. I've tried to manually change the theme in the manifest file, but the app won't even open if I do that.

Please, someone, help me! No amount of tutorials or useless Android documentation has any explanation as to why this is happening.

I have tried to sync Gradle files, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart, restarted IDE, restarted PC, cleaned project. The only thing I haven't done is uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio.

Comment: Why don't you try that part? (The only thing I haven't done is uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio.)

Comment: Probably you are editing the generated file not the `styles` file. Because when you edit the generated file and clean the code it will be regenerated using the values in the styles file. And so you will not see any changes. Just edit the styles file. Sync System files and you are good to go. If it doesn't work, try the option you have not done!

Comment: I'm definitely changing the styles file. I go into the values folder, open the styles.xml file and the click "open Theme Editor". I change my theme then close it and it doesn't change. I really don't want to have to re install Android Studio because I can't wait 6 weeks for the bloody NBN to download it :(

Comment: I've tried to to this on another PC and I'm still having the same problem.